# What is the meaning of this phrase or sentence

Tags: meaning, phrases

while reading the lesson **Bromides and Sulphides** I passed through this one sentence which was qouted.

> If you saw that sunset painted in a picture, you'd never believe it would be possible!

What does this mean ?

Comment: Please give more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there be little context to discern from, I will answer as best I can.

The sunset is so outstanding, ethereal, beautiful, resplendent, glorious, or some other such adjective that no one can trust its existence unless he see it with his own eyes.  A mere painting is not enough to prove such a thing; one needs to be there and witness it himself to truly believe that something so wondrous can be upon this mortal plane.  In short, 'pics or it didn't happen'.

If you provide further context, I may be able to elaborate--but what I have said is probably sufficient.

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient and I have got the point of the writer, actually it was just this qoute that writer wrote in his story. It was not from the story he was writing it was instead just a qoute or phrase used by him!